# MVC3 Custom Validation with Hierarchy Awareness

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, hierarchy, model-binding

I have a hierarchical model in MVC3.  All my basic validation is working, but I have a special validation that I can't figure out how to implement.

In my particular tree-hierarchy model, I have a field which must be unique/not repeat the values in any of its ancestral nodes.  In my case, peers do not have to be unique.

I've tried to inherit `ValidationAttribute` and use `validationContext.Items` to store a stack of parent nodes, but it doesn't seem to me that the `validationContext.Items` is shared between the validation of each level.  I don't know how to recursively call the validation on each child correctly, if that is appropriate.

If I'm `Validating` a particular node, I need access to the ancestral nodes, or some stack I create of the ancestral nodes passed to each child.

The solution shouldn't interfere with other validators or binders and should provide field-level errors rather than root-model level errors.  I also want to avoid `ThreadStatic,` reserved strings, and other magic tricks.  Yes, the entire hierarchy is bound in a single view using [this technique](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/).

Thanks!

Comment: In your model, does the object you are trying to validate have access to it's parent? In other words, is there a `.Parent` property?

Comment: Hi Steve - No, and furthermore the model itself shouldn't be involved.  The validator is pre-committment to a model instance.

Comment: can u show an example of ur code that shows ur parent and child controllers and how u use validating on them?

Comment: @uosɐſ, Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I don't think I was.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Could you create an action filter? This give you access to the modelstate and valueProvider so you could check the data and then adjust the Errors collection as necessary.

```
public class ValidateForUniqueAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     // filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model

       //  modelState[key].Errors.Add( .... )
  }

}


[ValidateForUnique]
public class YourController : Controller
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I don't think I understand completely.  How is ActionFilterAttribute better suited for this than the Validation Attribute?  I assume this gives me access to the full model for the action, but then I don't have access to each node (without implementing the model binding parts myself to convert the member to the correct modelState collection's key.

Comment: Are all the nodes in the model?

Comment: Well, "Model" being the graph of model instances, yes.  But it's more than one object instance (and more than one type, although they all adhere to one interface).